# Can I reconnect a normal chain with a quick link

Tags: chain

I have just mounted a chain, but I did it wrong and need to take it off. I have no more joining pins, but I have some spare quick links for this chain. Will they work even though the chain didn't come with them?

It came with a joining pin. I am asking because I don't want cut the chain for two inner ends and then realise it won't work.

Also, how can I mount them, if possible?

Answer (score 13):

You did not mention the type of your chain, but yes, quicklinks normally also work for other brands. SRAM quicklinks are known to work for Shimano chains etc.

Be aware that you must use 9-speed quicklinks for a 9-speed chain and similar. The widths differ so the the number of speeds must match.

You can solve some problems with wrong chain installation also by opening the derailleur cage (small screws), reinserting the chain, and closing agai. Under tension it could be tricky, though. Definitely take the chain off the crank first.

Comment: *Be aware that you should use 9-speed quicklinks for a 9-speed chain etc.*  I think that could be worded stronger.  A 10- or 11-speed quicklink won't work on a 9-speed chain, and worse, a quicklink for a wider chain on a narrow chain is dangerous.  If you put a 9-speed quicklink on an 11-speed chain, for example, the wider quicklink will protrude far enough so that it could catch on something like a derailleur cage with some pretty catastrophic results

Comment: Adding to that, the same number of speeds doesn't guarantee that the chain is same width. For example Connex quick link works with 9-speed Campagnolo chains, but SRAM does not.

Comment: @ojs That is exactly why I did not want to go into details... I was aware things like this can happen and I never used Campy and I did not want to dig the details elsewhere. The quicklinks usually say what systems they are compatible with on the packaging or in some other description. That said, users of Campagnolo  usually know what they are dealing with, it is far from being the mainstream and one usually buys it on purpose with some knowledge.

Comment: For Campy, once you get to 10s and up, I think any quick link of the same number of speeds should work. Exception is early 10s Campy chains, which were a bit wider than later models. Agree that very few people use Campy, so they can usually be ignored.